# PHP values comparing as neither true nor false

Tags: php, xml, comparison

I am pulling in XML data from an API using a SimpleXMLElement in PHP and iterating through the elements as follows:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement (file_get_contents ($api_url));
foreach ($xml->element as $element) {
    print $element->name;
}
```

Using this code, 12 element names are returned (which is correct).

However, as I iterate through these elements, I am wanting to skip any that are completed and continue processing the incomplete ones.

The XML being returned from the API is formatted like this:

```
<element>
    <name>Alpha</name>
    <completed>true</completed>
</element>
--or--
<element>
    <name>Beta</name>
    <completed>false</completed>
</element>
```

If I add an "if completed, then break" statement inside the foreach loop to bypass the completed elements, it only processes 1 element (there should be 7):

```
foreach ($xml->element as $element) {
    if ($element->completed == 'true')
        break;
    /* continue processing incomplete elements */
}
```

If I change the code to bypass the incomplete elements, it correctly returns the 5 incomplete elements names.

```
if ($element->completed == 'false')
    break;
```

It seems as though the other 6 elements are seen as both 'true' AND 'false' because they are skipped over in both of the above scenarios.

I have tried other comparisons as well, but none of them return the 7 incomplete elements.

```
=== 'true' (returns 12 elements)
=== 'false' (returns 12 elements)
== true (returns 0 elements)
== false (returns 12 elements)
=== true (returns 12 elements)
=== false (returns 12 elements)
```

There has to be something I'm overlooking - any guidance you can give would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you want `continue` rather than `break`, right?

Comment: If I echo `$element->completed`, I get 7x `false` and 5x `true`

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you please replace code

```
foreach ($xml->element as $element) {
    if ($element->find('completed')[0]->plaintext == 'true')
        break;
    /* continue processing incomplete elements */
}
```